# Scope with from import

Tags: python

I don't get how **import** and **from import** work regarding scope. Please look at the following example.

I have a class and an object in the file of the class that I would like to have a global scope.

```
# File alpha.py 
class Alpha():
    def __init__(self):
        self.alpha = 0
    def set(self, value):
        self.alpha = value
    def get(self):
        return self.alpha

# This is the global variable
alpha = None
```

In another file (control.py) I would like to access to the variable alpha in the file alpha.py so I use:

```
# File control.py
from alpha import alpha
def control():
    a = alpha.get()
    print ('Value of alpha in control ', a)
```

In the main.py I would like to make an instance of alpha like this:

```
# File main.py
from alpha import Alpha, alpha
alpha = Alpha()
alpha.set(1)
a = alpha.get()
print ('Value in main: ', a)

from control import control
control()
```

The result is (apparently the scope of alpha is local despite that I use from+import):

```
('Value in main ', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 11, in main
    control()
  File "control.py", line 4, in control
    a = alpha.get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

BUT if I use import with the full object path it works:

```
# File main2.py using simple import
import alpha
alpha.alpha = alpha.Alpha()

alpha.alpha.set(1)
a = alpha.alpha.get()
print ('Value in main ', a)

from control import control
control()
```

The result of calling main2.py is:

```
('Value in main ', 1)
('Value of alpha in control ', 1)
```

I was expecting the same behavior. What I am missing here?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

> This is related to the difference of memory manipulation between `local variables` VS `module members` in Python.

Modifying your code to show it:

```
# File alpha.py 
class Alpha():
    @staticmethod
    def getalpha():
        global alpha
        return alpha
alpha = None

# File control.py
from alpha import alpha
def control():
    print("control: ", id(alpha))
```

In **main.py**, `instance` will new a memory but not modify module itself.

`alpha = Alpha()`, alpha(**local variable in main.py**) is created as an instance Alpha() and allocate new memory for it. And then, **control.py** import the original module.

```
# File main.py
from alpha import Alpha, alpha
print("main: ", id(alpha), id(Alpha.getalpha())
alpha = Alpha()
print("main: ", id(alpha), id(Alpha.getalpha()))

from control import control
control()

('main: ', 4530210424, 4530210424) <--- initial value, initial value
('main: ', 4532198216, 4530210424) <--- <alpha.Alpha>, initial value
('control: ', 4530210424) <--- get member of original module
```

---

On the other hand, in **main2.py**, `members of module/class` will change their members value.

`alpha.alpha = alpha.Alpha()`, alpha.alpha(**member of alpha.py in main2.py**) is created as an instance Alpha() and allocate new memory for it. And then, **control.py** import the modified module.

```
# File main2.py using simple import
import alpha
print("main2: ", id(alpha.alpha), id(alpha.Alpha.getalpha()))
alpha.alpha = alpha.Alpha()
print("main2: ", id(alpha.alpha), id(alpha.Alpha.getalpha()))

from control import control
control()

('main2: ', 4425401976, 4425401976) <--- initial value, initial value
('main2: ', 4427402056, 4427402056) <--- <alpha.Alpha>, <alpha.Alpha>
('control: ', 4427402056) <--- get member of modified module
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually that is not the problem. What I want is to be able to have a shared object used by main.py who instantiate the object and control.py who read it. If you run the application both should read a value of 1.

Comment: @ErniTron Sorry for misunderstanding, I updated my answer, hope it is helpful for you.